# How to determine the torque and rpm of a Stirling engine?

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am actually working on making of a Stirling engine. I did some research work but most of the content on the internet is qualitative. So I am trying to build a small scale Stirling engine and trying to gather knowledge through trial and error way.

But since this is not my field of expertise so I thought to raise the question to the community first.

Suppose there is a Stirling engine whose Tcold is 0-degree Celsius and Thot is 200-degree Celsius.
The piston is 35mm in diameter and the stroke is 24mm.
The engine is made to run using air at a pressure of 2 bar.

Can anyone help me to determine the torque and rpm of this engine?

Comment: Perhaps because other tags are more than relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It will be determined by the system load and internal friction factors.

Here's some initial thoughts on how to determien this:

Your power, $P$, is equal to the product of the torque, $\tau$ and your angular velocity, $\omega$,

$$
P = \tau \omega.
$$

Assuming a completely adiabatic system,
$$
\dot Q = P,
$$
where $\dot Q$ is your heat in.

Therefore, you'd be able to write,

$$
\tau = \frac{\dot Q}{\omega}.
$$

Now, what you need to know from your system is, $\omega = f(\tau)$.  how much torque is required to produce a certain angular velocity.  Once you know this, the intersection of the two curves give you your operating point.

Comment: one of the curve is w=f(torque) but what is the other curve?

Comment: It's the curve of the system.  How much torque is required to produce a certain rotational velocity.  This can be measured or derived through system modeling.  It should be noted, this would only be for steady state analysis.  Transient analysis is another matter.